# Delphi 10 Seattle Automated Builds

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, build-server

I'm trying to add automated builds of our Delphi 10 Seattle projects to our build server (which currently builds all our .NET and Java projects).
Now that Delphi uses MSBUILD it integrates well with TeamCity.

I can build things locally on a machine with Delphi 10 Seattle installed.

I want to run the builds on the server without having to install the full IDE if at all possible.

I've followed the instructions in
[this article](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Setting_up_a_Delphi_Build_Machine) and in 
[this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916132/what-is-the-minimal-agent-install-footprint-for-delphi-build-automation)

When running on the server, the builds fail due to the following error (second line, first is build command):

```
[15:24:24][DCC] c:\Delphi\17.0\bin\dcc32.exe -$O- -$W+ --no-config -B -Q -TX.exe -AGenerics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;Generics.Defaults=System.Generics.Defaults;WinTypes=Winapi.Windows;WinProcs=Winapi.Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE -DDEBUG -E..\..\MODASMobileServer\Win32\Debug -I..\..\Source\Common;..\..\Source\Interfaces;..\..\Source\Messages;..\..\Source\Language\English;c:\Delphi\17.0\lib\Win32\Debug -NU..\..\Temp\MODASMobileServer\Win32\Debug -NSWinapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Vcl.Touch;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Shell; -O..\..\Source\Common;..\..\Source\Interfaces;..\..\Source\Messages;..\..\Source\Language\English;c:\Delphi\17.0\lib\Win32\Debug -R..\..\Source\Common;..\..\Source\Interfaces;..\..\Source\Messages;..\..\Source\Language\English;c:\Delphi\17.0\lib\Win32\Debug -U..\..\Source\Common;..\..\Source\Interfaces;..\..\Source\Messages;..\..\Source\Language\English;c:\Delphi\17.0\lib\Win32\Debug -V -VN -NO..\..\Temp\MODASMobileServer\Win32\Debug   MODASMobileServer.dpr   
[15:24:24][DCC] This version of the product does not support command line compiling.
```

Clearly it thinks it isn't licensed properly.

The BIN, BIN64 and LIB directories were copied over from a fully registered and working installation.

What do I need to do in order to get XE10 projects building on a build server without installing the IDE? Or do I need to resign myself to installing the IDE?

Comment: You need to register the installation. Frankly an install into a VM seems like the best option.

Comment: "*Now that Delphi uses MSBUILD*" - FYI, Delphi/C++Builder/RADStudio has been [using MSBuild since 2007](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/What's_New_in_RAD_Studio_%28Delphi_for_Win32_2007%29).

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I know, but we've been on a long slow upgrade process from Delphi5 => XE2 => XE10 !

Comment: and thanks to whoever for the downvote - would have been nice to know why

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I know that people don't like the product being called XE10. It is Delphi 10 Seattle. No XE in the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out. Although I had what seemed like a fully functioning install of Delphi 10, I remembered that I had originally installed it from a trial.
The trial has been properly licensed, so I had assumed that it was now a pukka installation.
This was not the case, there is clearly some difference between a registered trial version and proper installation.

To resolve this issue I:

- uninstalled the trial from the dev machine
- downloaded the full ISO version from EDN
- installed the full ISO version on the dev machine
- licensed / registered the install on the dev machine
- copied over the bin, bin64, lib, imports, include, lib folders to C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\ on the build server

Re-ran the build and it worked successfully.