# How to install Delphi 10.4 Sydney command line compiler (on Windows Server 2016)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

We are trying to set up 10.4 Sydney automated builds based on the Delphi command-line compiler. Our build servers are Windows Server 2016, but RAD Studio 10.4 is supported only for Windows 10 and attempts to install on Windows Server 2016 have failed. Embarcadero technical support says to purchase RAD Server, but is RAD Server really intended to support automated builds?

Would manual setup be a solution? Is it feasible to manually set up the Delphi 10.4 command-line compiler on Windows Server 2016 (i.e. copy over needed files and import needed Registry settings)? Or will 10.4 install on Server despite this not being officially supported (with our woes being due to heretofore unidentified IS policies or security settings which are interfering with the setup)?

**Edit:** The error is "No valid license information found for Embarcadero Delphi 10.4. You must provide a valid serial number in order to use Embarcadero Delphi 10.4 Do you want to run the registration wizard again?"

Comment: What is the failure message?

Comment: Maybe a good solution is to use a VM to run your automated build on Windows Server 2016. You VM could run Win10. I think WSRV2016 has Hyper-V built-in.

Comment: @fpiette "No valid license information found for Embarcadero Delphi 10.4. You must provide a valid serial number in order to use Embarcadero Delphi 10.4 Do you want to run the registration wizard again?"

Comment: The installer could not contact the licensing server, so I opted to manually import the license. That was the message I got.

Comment: That message has nothing to do with Server 2016 not being supported. It has to do with not having a valid license file for that machine. Contact EMBT support to ask them how to get that license file.

Comment: I have a named Delphi user license; shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: You have to correctly follow the process of registration explained on screen. You can't import a license generated on another system. And you are not allowed to install Delphi on several computers. The number of installations is limited and if you go beyond that limit, you have to contact Embarcadero sales to get your count increased if you provide correct explanation.

Comment: The machine in question cannot contact the licensing server; something is blocking the registration wizard. So far, I've only been able to get 10.4 working in a VM (which is fine for development, but not for unattended builds). I can't get 10.4 to install in a corporate desktop.

Comment: You could ask Embarcadero to convert your "Named User" license to a "Network Named User" license. That would allow you to install that (new) license on multiple (no restriction there) computers and use it on several in parallel (I seem to remember that 3 is allowed, so that would cover your build server and your work PC). You would have to install a license server in your network for that to work, but your computers won't need an internet connection to activate the license, only network access to the license server. The user account on all the computers would have to be the same.

Comment: Converting "Named User" to "Network Named User" requires an active subscription.

Comment: You don't need to use a full install of Delphi on a build server, only the parts that are required by MSBuild. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916132/what-is-the-minimal-agent-install-footprint-for-delphi-build-automation for more information. Main thing to consider is the library paths, by default from EnvOptions.proj. Can be overridden using the DelphiLibraryPath property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution (suggested by our Embarcadero sales rep, not their tech support, who refused to help because 10.4 is not officially supported on Windows Server 2016) was to uninstall 10.4 (what little had installed) and then reinstall. Reinstalling, the installer found the manually-imported license (the same one that it had complained held no valid license information) and allowed the install to proceed. There were no further issues with the install and now both the Delphi 10.4 IDE and command prompt are working properly.

Comment: Do all command line compilers work? I am also running D10.4 on a 2016 server as Build server but the command line compilers for all platforms other than Windows fail with not findung DCUs that are definitevely in the path. Embarcadero support finally stated that these compilers are not supported on 2016 and adviced me to switch to 2019. I did not try it as I gave up upon the other platforms and use Wine.

Comment: Not sure. Our Delphi apps are Windows-only.