# How to get past the Embarcadero Product Registration Dialog when installing Delphi 10.4 CE

Tags: delphi

I'm attempting to install Delphi 10.4 Community Edition on a Windows 10 machine which previously had the full version installed (that license is now expired).  The previous licence was an Academic licence and these have to be renewed annually.

I've followed the instructions from activation.embarcadero.com:

> Thank you for registering! The attached file (reg6072_1665758099000.txt) activates your copy of Embarcadero product.
>
> INSTRUCTIONS:
>
> 1. First place the file into any folder on your hard drive, My Documents for example.
> 2. Then launch the product. If your copy has not been activated before, the Embarcadero Product Registration Dialog will come up.
> 3. Click the Advanced button in the registration dialog.  Click on Import.  Navigate to and import the license.
>
> If the product is already running, go to Help | License Manager... in the menu. Click on Import; navigate to and import the license.

However, after I do that, the Registration Wizard closes and I get this pop-up:

> No valid licence information found for Embarcadero (r) Delphi 10.4.  You must provide a valid serial number to use Embarcadero (r) Delphi 10.4.  Do you want to run the registration wizard again?
>
> Registration code 12963955
>
> You are not licensed to use Embarcadero (r) Delphi 10.4.

In case the problem is being caused by a remnant of the previous, Academic version,  I've deleted

- the whole of Program Files(x86)\Embarcadero and below
- all the registry keys and values containing 'Embarcadero'
- the Embarcadero folder below AppData\Roaming
- all references in the system path to the Embarcadero and below folders

and I still get the problem.

So I'm stuck.  How to get it to accept the registration file and get the installation to proceed?

Comment: AFAIK, full licenses never expire. Only subscriptions and temporary (one year) licenses expire.

Comment: Thanks, Uwe.  It was an academic licence, and they need renewing annually.

Comment: In that case you need to remove the old license completely from the system before installing Delphi 10.4.2 CE. This may include deleting some files manually.

Comment: @UweRaabe: Thanks.  I've removed the Emb directory under Program Files(x86), all the regstry entries for it, all the path entries in the system path and the Emb folder under AppData and still I get the same error message.

Comment: I found his answer working for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/65147832/14062144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out for myself.  The penny dropped after I added a comment to the q to explain to Uwe Raabe what I'd removed of my previous set-up.

It turns out that in addition to my own AppData\Roaming profile I also needed the delete the Embarcadero folders from the Public\Roaming and All users\Roaming folders.  Then, the Licence Registration wizard ran without complaint and the installation run to a successful completion.

A word of warning: if you have more that one Delphi installation you should obviously restrict your deletions to the D10.4 one.

Comment: Just a quick note: As far as I know, CE is a one year expiring license. So expect to be forced ask for a new CE license next year. And you'll only get one for the latest CE version available at that time. CE is usually one version before the current one. This is probably why you've got a 10.4 license while current version is 11.2.

Comment: Thanks, @fpiette.  My IDE is telling me I have 367 days left, so I think you may be right.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in dealing with expired Delphi licenses is with the use of Embarcadero License Manager that you can find in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin` folder.

With Licence Manager it is possible to switch between Educational and Community Edition license without the need of reinstalling Delphi or manually deleting any files.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work with a damaged installation.  Better yet. because of the confounded Registration Wizard and the faulty logic it's based upon, you can't even do  a re-install to fix things.